# Does the Lord delight in the death of the wicked?

Tags: contradiction, 1-samuel

Does 1 Samuel 2:25 contradict with God’s character in Ezekiel 18:23, 33:11? On one hand it says the Lord desired or delighted to kill the wicked sons of Eli. On the other it says he takes no delight or desire in the death of the wicked.

1 Samuel 2:25 (NASB95) “If one man sins against another, God will mediate for him; but if a man sins against the LORD, who can intercede for him?” But they would not listen to the voice of their father, for the LORD desired to put them to death.

Ezekiel 18:23 (NASB95)
“Do I have any pleasure in the death of the wicked,” declares the Lord GOD, “rather than that he should turn from his ways and live?

Ezekiel 33:11 (NASB95)
“Say to them, ‘As I live!’ declares the Lord GOD, ‘I take no pleasure in the death of the wicked, but rather that the wicked turn from his way and live. Turn back, turn back from your evil ways! Why then will you die, O house of Israel?’

Comment: 'Desire' to do something does not imply a 'delight' in doing so. Righteousness requires judgment, where mercy is inappropriate. But mercy delighteth in opposition to judgment (in those circumstances where mercy may be applied). Up-voted +1.

Comment: We are obliged to describe God's actions in human language, because that's all we've got, but it isn't safe to attribute to him the emotions implied by the words we choose. That gives us a misleading picture of him.

Answer (score 4):

The answer to this question is found in understanding the difference between a desire and a pleasure. God desired to put those sons to death. He takes no pleasure in doing so.

One can imagine how this is so. A person could desire to lose weight for a variety of reasons such as for a job, but then take no pleasure in the process of losing weight or even in the final state. Likewise, God may desire to put these sons to death as a matter of justice or order, but nevertheless not take any pleasure in the process or the final state of the one killed.

Comment: +1. Good simple answer.